Substantial difference between GOOGLEFINANCE on sheets and on-platform
I'm using GOOGLEFINANCE to plot SPARKLINE miniatures of forex currencies. I use these miniatures as a preview, looking for any interesting patterns, so that I can inspect details on Google Finance later on.
The problem is that the sparklines look nothing like what I see on Google Finance, sometimes even displaying an opposing trend.
An example.
This is the sparkline I get for a 30 day history of EURALL (Euro/Albanian Lek):

This is what I get from Google Finance:

Not only are the trend lines incredibly different, but the percentage change doesn't even resemble; -0.55 on my calculation and +1.98% on GF.
This is how I plot the sparkline:
=Sparkline(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURALL", "price", TODAY()-30, TODAY()))

And this is how I calculate the percentage change:
=CURRENCYCHANGE(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURALL", "price", TODAY()-30, TODAY()))

Where CURRENCYCHANGE is a custom Apps Script function, as follows:
function CURRENCYCHANGE(array) {
  let open = array[1][1]
  let close = array[array.length - 1][1]

  return 100 * (close - open) / open
}

I think that the calculations are right, is it just the GF API that is giving me different information? What should I do?
